# How to install vncserver with a password?

Tags: centos, vnc-server

I am trying to install tigervnc-server from a bash script with a password under Centos 6. 
I want to do this because I want to automate VPS installations. Does anybody know how to do this? Tried adding two lines in the script with the password because it requires you to enter a password 2 times but it didnt worked, it said command not found and I didnt got past it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Options:
PASSWORD="mysecret"
DISPLAY=":10"
VNCSERVER_OPTIONS="-geometry 1024x768 -alwaysshared"
PASSWD_PATH="$HOME/.vnc/passwd"
XSTARTUP_PATH="$HOME/.vnc/xstartup"
VNCSERVER="tightvncserver"
VNCPASSWD="tightvncpasswd"
# NOTE: you can change `tightvncpasswd` by `vncpasswd` if you don't use
#       TightVNC but it won't work in some VNC implementations
NEW_SESSION="exec gnome-session"

vncserver_stop() {
    # Kill server for this display if is running
    $VNCSERVER -clean -kill $DISPLAY
}

vncserver_start() {
    echo "$PASSWORD" | $VNCPASSWD -f > $PASSWD_PATH
    chmod 600 $PASSWD_PATH
    echo "$NEW_SESSION" > $XSTARTUP_PATH
    $VNCSERVER $DISPLAY $VNCSERVER_OPTIONS
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        vncserver_start
    ;;

    stop)
        vncserver_stop
    ;;

    restart)
       tightvnc_stop
       tightvnc_start
    ;;


    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart>"
        exit 1
esac
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, I found a shorter solution for this though.


`mypass="mypass"

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn "$prog"
expect "Password:"
send "$mypass\r"
expect "Verify:"
send "$mypass\r"
expect eof
exit
EOF`